Learn about shirk
Assalamu alaikum.Bangladesh is a democratic country.Here are some law in constitution which are given below-
1.Subject to law, public order and morality
(a) Every citizen has the right to adopt, practice or propagate any religion;
(b) Every religious community and sub-community has the right to establish, maintain and manage its own religious institutions.
2.Any person who has a "willful" or "malicious" intention to "hurt religious sentiments" will be punished with imprisonment.
Are these law considered as shirk? My another question : is it shirk giving safety to non muslim's place of worship for keeping communal harmony?

